# Express server causes error "This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a simple hello world kind of server using **Express**.
Here goes my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/",function(request, response){//what to do when someone make get request to the homepage or route
  console.log(request);
  response.send("hello");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server is listening at port 3000");
});
```

When I run the program I see this at the command prompt:

`server is listening at port 3000`

But when I'm accessing it through a browser *i.e.* `https://localhost:3000`, I'm getting an error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid
>   response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I expect the browser to see `hello` as per my method, above, `response.send("hello")`

Comment: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR means SSL  gives you a green lock at the top left side of address bar, you can't do that with localhost, it's the **s** in **http(s)**

Comment: although you can still generate SSL for localhost , but you don't need it, just request ```http://localhost:3000```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to access it through the `HTTP` protocol instead. try to connect to `http://localhost:3000` instead of `https://localhost:3000`.

Comment: If changing to http does not work for you: in chrome, go to url: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

Under Delete domain security policies enter `localhost` or your problem domain and click the delete button on screen

Then retry with changing `https` to `http`.

Answer (score 6):

Basically what `app.listen` does is that it creates an http server and listens on it, so you have to use `http` protocol to access it and not `https`.

This is the source code for app listen taken from express:
[app.listen](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L616)